# A question over Gorenstein local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(R,{\frak m})$ be a Gorenstein local ring and $M$ and $N$ be two indecomposable finitely generated $R$-modules such that $\dim M= \dim N=\dim  R=n$. Suppose that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)‎\cong‎ \operatorname{Hom}_R(N,R)\neq 0 $ and $H^n_{\frak m}(M) \cong H^n_{\frak m}(N)$ (where $H^n_{\frak m}(-)$ denotes the $n$-th right derived functor of $\Gamma _{\frak m}(-)$). Can we conclude that $M \cong N$?

Comment: What is $n$? $\dim R$? All $n$?

Comment: $dim \, R=dim \,N=dim M=n$.

Comment: @MohammadBagheri, please add all relevant information to the body of the question itself.

Comment: Thanks. It's done.

Comment: If $R$ is a dvr, for ANY finite length module $M$, you have $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R)=0$ and $H^1_{\mathfrak{m}}(M)=0$. So, your question has a negative answer without further hypothesis, since you can take $M=R\oplus R/\mathfrak{m}$ and $N=R$.

Comment: That's right. I will add some new hypothesis to the question.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These assumptions are still not enough. Let $\dim R=n\geq 2$ and let $I$ be an ideal generated by a maximal regular sequence. Then both $I,R$ are indecomposable, their duals are just $R$ and $H^n_{\mathfrak{m}}(I)=H^n_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$.